# Angular 2.0.0 Metadata_resolver weird behavior

Tags: angular

I'm migrating my app from angular2 RC5 with [angular-webpack](https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack) scaffolding to angular 2 2.0.0 with angular cli beta 14.

I'm fighting with those errors:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for PublicInfoDao: (?,
>   ?).CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata @
>   metadata_resolver.js:508CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata @
>   metadata_resolver.js:405(anonymous function) @
>   metadata_resolver.js:552CompileMetadataResolver.getProvidersMetadata @
>   metadata_resolver.js:532CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @
>   metadata_resolver.js:285RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents @
>   runtime_compiler.js:126RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @
>   runtime_compiler.js:64RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync @
>   runtime_compiler.js:55PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @
>   application_ref.js:303PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @
>   application_ref.js:285(anonymous function) @
>   main.ts:13__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap db3609d…:52(anonymous
>   function) @ .*$:7__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap
>   db3609d…:52webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap db3609d…:23(anonymous
>   function) @ main.bundle.js:1

and

> metadata_resolver.js:278Uncaught Error: Unexpected value
>   'AppComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'(anonymous function)
>   @ metadata_resolver.js:278CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata
>   @ metadata_resolver.js:265RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents @
>   runtime_compiler.js:126RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @
>   runtime_compiler.js:64RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync @
>   runtime_compiler.js:55PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @
>   application_ref.js:303PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @
>   application_ref.js:285(anonymous function) @
>   main.ts:13__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap db3609d…:52(anonymous
>   function) @ .*$:7__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap
>   db3609d…:52webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap db3609d…:23(anonymous
>   function) @ main.bundle.js:1   [1](https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack):
>   https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack

It's a weird behavior cause if I remove several components the app works. But if I add a simplecomponent like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tl-result-item',
  templateUrl: "./resultitem.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./resultitem.component.scss"]
})
export class ResultItemComponent {

  @Input()
  result:Result;

  constructor(){}
}
```

The second error is thrown. If I comment `@Input()` the app works.
There are some services if I uncomment the app throws same error and If I comment some lines the error disapears.

I'm going crazy with those errors. I'm thinking it should be an external issue.

Any idea?

**Update:**

The first error could be related to https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter#frequently-asked-questions (second question) 
I have several problem to migrate to angular 2.0.0 final.

**Update2:**

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    MetaService,
    Title,
    HttpInterceptor,
    {provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: XHRBackend},
    {provide: Http, useExisting: HttpInterceptor},
    {provide: Configuration, useClass: ConfigurationDevelopment}
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    // APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ResultItemComponent,

    TimestampToMomentPipe,
    TimestampToTimePipe
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Update3:**
Another example of code that fails in angular cli.

This code works properly:

```
this.publicService.all().subcribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
});
```

This code fails:

```
this.publicService.all().subcribe(response => {
      deserialize(response)
});
```

Exception explained above:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for PublicInfoDao: (?,
>   ?).

¿¿??

Comment: Do you have a github repo that reproduces this problem?

Comment: No, but I can verify the problem is related with angular-cli. I'm using the old scaffold and angular 2.0.0 works fine. So what happens with angular-cli?

Comment: can you share your app.module file?

Comment: Here you are, what do you think about? I want to know any idea you have.

Comment: i thought that you import  wrong something to app.module.But Everything is clear.Maybe you can import providers wrongly.You can create called environment file for importing providers.https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/environment.ts

Comment: the constructor of PublicInfoDao takes two arguments. What are those two arguments; which Type are those? And where do you import those Types from?

Comment: The args are Configuration and Http

Answer (score 1):

environment.ts

```
// Angular 2
// rc2 workaround
import { enableDebugTools, disableDebugTools } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { enableProdMode, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
// Environment Providers
let PROVIDERS: any[] = [
  // common env directives
];

// Angular debug tools in the dev console
// https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/86405345b781a9dc2438c0fbe3e9409245647019/TOOLS_JS.md
let _decorateModuleRef = function identity<T>(value: T): T { return value; };

if ('production' === ENV) {
  // Production
  disableDebugTools();
  enableProdMode();

  PROVIDERS = [
    ...PROVIDERS,
    // custom providers in production
  ];

} else {

  _decorateModuleRef = (modRef: any) => {
    const appRef = modRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
    const cmpRef = appRef.components[0];

    let _ng = (<any>window).ng;
    enableDebugTools(cmpRef);
    (<any>window).ng.probe = _ng.probe;
    (<any>window).ng.coreTokens = _ng.coreTokens;
    return modRef;
  };

  // Development
  PROVIDERS = [
    ...PROVIDERS,
    // custom providers in development
  ];

}

export const decorateModuleRef = _decorateModuleRef;

export const ENV_PROVIDERS = [
  ...PROVIDERS
];
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
 // expose our Services and Providers into Angular"s dependency injection
        ENV_PROVIDERS
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    // APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ResultItemComponent,

    TimestampToMomentPipe,
    TimestampToTimePipe
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: It's ok, add enviroments is good, but it's not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are using export barrels like this:

```
export * from 'some-file';
export * from 'another-file';
```

in this case you might run into circular dependencies, altough you sourcecode in itself does not have any circular dependecies.

Sometimes the error-message

> Cannot resolve all parameters (some,thing,?)

indicates that you have a circular dependency.

You might try importing your components by directly specifying the needed file, without using export-barrels bundled in index.ts-files

you might want to look into this so-question:

[Barrel Import Appears To Break Load Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398829/barrel-import-appears-to-break-load-order)

---

...your question might actually be a duplicate of this one :-)

[Angular 2 DI Error - EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/angular-2-di-error-exception-cant-resolve-all-parameters)

Comment: The question is... why is my code running over angular-webpack scaffold with angular 2.0.0, and fails if I runs it over angular-cli? I've been searching for "export *" in my code: 0 results. Anyway, thanks for explaining me the error and give me information.

Comment: [wild-guessing:on] maybe the two processes treat exports and imports differently? I myself have completly lost track of compiletime and runtime concerning these new WebDev-Tools [wild-guessing:off]